# onBlur event conflicting with Alert.alert

Tags: react-native, alert, textinput

Alert is creating the problem of losing the focus in TextInput.

```
<TextInput onBlur = {() => Alert.alert('focus has been gone from TextInput')} onChangeText = {(text) => Alert.alert('u input something')} />
```

When I am entering the data, first I am getting alert for onChangeText but consequently due to the onBlur.
Is there any way to stop text input to lose focus on Alert opening

Comment: Why do you need to alert in the onChangeText ? Indeed the TextInput will lose focus because of the alert, it should be that why because the focus will be on the alert

Comment: Actually alert is not being shown directly but if the input is not in some specific range we need to show the user the correct range and on blur is required to check if the user entered in the correct range.

Let the range is 800 to 900 so we will not let him enter anything else than 8, 9 for the first place and thus how we will check for the entire range but on blur even is required so that we can detect if the user has entered the all three numbers. like 82 is also valid but when the user is leaving the text input we can stop him by giving a proper range message.

Comment: Ok then you can make a function that will be triggered on onBlur, this function check the value that the user entered. If the value is not good: 1) do you alert 2) programmatically "re focus" the TextInput.

Comment: OK the problem is suppose there are two consecutive text input I am working on first and after filling the value and if I go to the second one, the Alert will open (let I have entered a out of range value in the first one) but at this moment the onBlur of the second text input will also run as at this time my focus was on the second one.

Comment: Indeed. What about not doing an Alert, but a simple error message in a Text component below your TextInput. It's better to do it this way because the user can continue to fill the second TextInput, and then going back to the first TextInput. Also this way the onBlur function will just check if the value is Ok and then display / undisplay the error message.

Comment: My requirement is quite different. In my application all the messages are being shown in alert. Perhaps I am not able to explain you here complete requirement. but to keep it simple and avoiding the workarounds I posted my question : is it possible to  avoid onBlur event to be executed if another alert is opened and at that time focus was on the textinput.
Currently It seems a bug if your text input has an Alert in the callback and an alert opend by any other operation  your text input blur function will run if at that time you were on the textinput

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211554/discussion-between-cr7-and-akhil-singhal).